# Programmatically create custom document packages in Docusign when populating from Salesforce

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to programmatically create document packages in DocuSign? We are looking for the ability to create a package with select documents depending on the recipient and demographic data from Salesforce. Since there may be many permutations of packages, manually creating templates is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, by "document packages" you mean templates, then yes, it can be done programmatically.

[A full example in Node.JS that programmatically creates a DocuSign template](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg008.js) is available. You can test it by installing the [repo](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant) -- see example 8.

The software is being ported to other languages too.